# Sql sum() columns from different tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Category Table

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM cats;
+------+------+-----------+
| c_id | p_id | c_name    |
+------+------+-----------+
|    1 |    1 | cats 1    |
|    2 |    1 | cats 2    |
|    3 |    1 | cats 3    |
+------+------+-----------+
```

Meta Table

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM meta;
+------+------+------+---------+-------------+-------+
| m_id | p_id | c_id | name    | description | costs |
+------+------+------+---------+-------------+-------+
|    1 |    1 |    1 | Abhijit | description | 100   |
|    2 |    1 |    1 | Abhijit | description | 200   |
|    3 |    1 |    2 | Abhiji2 | description | 500   |
+------+------+------+---------+-------------+-------+
```

Transaction Table

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM transactions;
+------+------+------+---------------------+--------+
| t_id | p_id | m_id | date                | amount |
+------+------+------+---------------------+--------+
|    1 |    1 |    1 | 2016-02-16 11:17:06 | 50     |
|    2 |    1 |    1 | 2016-02-16 11:17:06 | 50     |
|    3 |    1 |    2 | 2016-02-16 11:17:06 | 50     |
|    4 |    1 |    2 | 2016-02-16 11:17:06 | 150    |
+------+------+------+---------------------+--------+
```

I want to sum() for each category costs (from meta table) and amount( from transaction table).

I use:

```
mysql> SELECT c.*, SUM(t.amount), SUM(m.costs)
    FROM cats c
        LEFT JOIN meta m ON m.c_id=c.c_id
        LEFT JOIN transactions t ON t.m_id=m.m_id
    GROUP BY c.c_id;

+------+------+-----------+--------+---------------+--------------+
| c_id | p_id | c_name    | add_by | SUM(t.amount) | SUM(m.costs) |
+------+------+-----------+--------+---------------+--------------+
|    1 |    1 | Abhijit   |      1 |           100 |          400 |
|    2 |    1 | Abhiji2   |      1 |           200 |          500 |
+------+------+-----------+--------+---------------+--------------+
```

It's wrong. The Costs of cats id **1** is **300** but here I got **400**

I Want Get Return From Query Like This:

```
+------+------+-----------+--------+---------------+--------------+
| c_id | p_id | c_name    | add_by | SUM(t.amount) | SUM(m.costs) |
+------+------+-----------+--------+---------------+--------------+
|    1 |    1 | Abhijit   |      1 |           100 |          300 |
|    2 |    1 | Abhiji2   |      1 |           200 |          500 |
+------+------+-----------+--------+---------------+--------------+
```

Comment: run the query without SUMs and GROUP to see whats wrong

Comment: You're selecting from `con_cats` in your SUM query, but you select from `cats` in your first query.

Comment: No No No just typing mistreat. table name is cats

Comment: @ABHIJIT an sql fiddle would have helped a lot for the answer.

Comment: I believe there is a problem in one of your JOIN conditions.  It could be a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you had a typo (or error) in one of your `JOIN` conditions.  I think you intended your original query to be this:

```
SELECT c.*, SUM(t.amount), SUM(m.costs)
FROM cats c
    LEFT JOIN meta m ON m.c_id = c.c_id
    LEFT JOIN transactions t ON t.m_id = m.c_id
GROUP BY c.c_id;
```

Note carefully `ON t.m_id = m.c_id`, which agrees with your expected output.  In any case, I reworked your query as follows:

```
SELECT c.c_id, c.p_id, c.c_name, t2.transactionCosts, t1.metaCosts
FROM cats c
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT c_id, SUM(costs) AS metaCosts
    FROM meta
    GROUP BY c_id
) t1
    ON c.c_id = t1.c_id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT m_id, SUM(amount) AS transactionCosts
    FROM transactions
    GROUP BY m_id
) t2
    ON c.c_id = t2.m_id
WHERE t2.transactionCosts IS NOT NULL OR t1.metaCosts IS NOT NULL;
```

The first subquery computes the meta total for each `c_id`, and the second subquery computes the transaction total for each `m_id`.  These results are then both joined together with the `cats` table to get your final result.

**Follow the link below for a running demo:**

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc24a0/5)

Comment: PLEASE can you explain this query for me to better understanding it.

Comment: or any use full link for this . PLEASE

Comment: @ABHIJIT I added an explanation.  Feel free to test each piece of my query separately in Fiddle so that you can understand what is happening.

Comment: Can you tell me the best way to learn sql(any book for website or tutorials) More deepth. **PLEASE**

Comment: The best way to learn SQL is by doing it in real life.  That failing, answering/studying Stack Overflow question is a good alternative.  [Tech on the Net](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/) is a very good site which I use often.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you select c.* but only group by c_id, in this case you have 2 options. window function or subquery.

via over(partition by):

```
SELECT c.*, 
       SUM(t.amount)over(partition by c.c_id) as amount,
       SUM(m.costs)over(partition by c.c_id) as cost
FROM con_cats c
    LEFT JOIN meta m ON m.c_id=c.c_id
    LEFT JOIN transactions t ON t.m_id=m.m_id;
```

via subquery:

```
select a.*,b.amount,b.costs from con_cats a 
inner join
(SELECT c.c_id, SUM(t.amount) as amount, SUM(m.costs) as costs
FROM con_cats c
    LEFT JOIN meta m ON m.c_id=c.c_id
    LEFT JOIN transactions t ON t.m_id=m.m_id
GROUP BY c.c_id) b
on a.c_id = b.c_id;
```

Comment: He is using MySQL, so I don't believe he will have window functions at his disposal.

Comment: @ABHIJIT you tried both? i didn't notice the mysql so window function will go wrong, but the subquery should work

Comment: @ABHIJIT oops, it's c_id, sorry about that. get it done